# Unable to read multiple web pages

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I would like to take information from those two pages that are similar:

http://www.quotenet.com/index/market-movers/S&P_500
http://www.quotenet.com/index/market-movers/CAC_40

I already have a code that works for one page (I want to get the first two movers in the table):

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument
Dim TopMoverTable As Object
Dim TopMoverTable2 As Object



Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


ie.navigate "http://www.quotenet.com/index/market-movers/S&P_500"

       Do
       DoEvents
       Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

       Set doc = ie.document

      Set TopMoverTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(2)


Cells(1, 2) = Split(TopMoverTable.getElementsByTagName("TD")(0).innerText, vbCrLf)(0)
Cells(1, 3) = Split(TopMoverTable.getElementsByTagName("TD")(4).innerText, vbCrLf)(1)




Cells(2, 2) = Split(TopMoverTable.getElementsByTagName("TD")(11).innerText, vbCrLf)(0)
Cells(2, 3) = Split(TopMoverTable.getElementsByTagName("TD")(15).innerText, vbCrLf)(1)

'ie.navigate "http://www.quotenet.com/index/market-movers/CAC_40"
'       Do
'       DoEvents
'       Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
'
'       Set doc = ie.document
'
'      Set TopMoverTable2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(2)


ie.Application.Quit
```

I commented the code that does not work.

How I can read those two pages?

Comment: What line does it error on? What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing **TopMoverTable2** in your code. Now, I have manipulated your code.

**Try below code**

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument
Dim TopMoverTable As Object
Dim TopMoverTable2 As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate "http://www.quotenet.com/index/market-movers/S&P_500"

   Do
   DoEvents
   Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

   Set doc = ie.document

   Set TopMoverTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(2)


Cells(1, 2) = Split(TopMoverTable.getElementsByTagName("TD")  (0).innerText, vbCrLf)(0)
Cells(1, 3) = Split(TopMoverTable.getElementsByTagName("TD")(4).innerText, vbCrLf)(1)

Cells(2, 2) = Split(TopMoverTable.getElementsByTagName("TD")(11).innerText, vbCrLf)(0)
Cells(2, 3) = Split(TopMoverTable.getElementsByTagName("TD")(15).innerText, vbCrLf)(1)


ie.navigate "http://www.quotenet.com/index/market-movers/CAC_40"
   Do
   DoEvents
   Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

   Set doc = ie.document

  Set TopMoverTable2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(2)


Cells(5, 2) = Split(TopMoverTable2.getElementsByTagName("TD")(0).innerText, vbCrLf)(0)
Cells(5, 3) = Split(TopMoverTable2.getElementsByTagName("TD")(4).innerText, vbCrLf)(1)

Cells(6, 2) = Split(TopMoverTable2.getElementsByTagName("TD")(11).innerText, vbCrLf)(0)
Cells(6, 3) = Split(TopMoverTable2.getElementsByTagName("TD")(15).innerText, vbCrLf)(1)

ie.Application.Quit
```

Comment: The Code Works for 2 Websites, But I need to fetch 10 websites in my code, it works as well but gets really slow. Is there another method like using thread or async to make it quicker ?

Comment: It takes less than a minute to fetch data from 2 websites. Do you want more faster than half minute ??????

Comment: 2 Websites is ok, but when I do it for 10 websites it gets slow